# Does V8 detect int variables and handle them more efficiently?

Tags: javascript, performance, variables, types, v8

This is more about Node.JS, which uses the V8 engine. This is the JavaScript engine that is also used for Google Chrome.

I hear about V8 being really fast, not just for Node, but for browsers too. However, one thing I notice about JavaScript, is that types are not coded for variables.

To accomplish this in Java, you would need an `Object` variable type for everything. This would be significantly less efficient in, for example, a `for` loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {}
```

My question is, how does V8 handle variable types? Does it know that this `i` variable is always either an `int` or `long`? (I see this as unlikely beause, `i++` has the ability to convert a `long` to a `double`.)

Or does V8 handle things in such a way that it does not matter? I think some simple examples of what the JIT compiler would create would be useful. Both Java and JavaScript do have JIT compilers to convert code to C.

I am not a C programmer, but I am curious to know how types are handled, and if Java is really more efficient in that area. (yes, I know that I/O is going to be much more significant for most programs than type handling)

Comment: *"types are not coded for variables"* -- the term you're looking for here is *dynamically typed* (as opposed to *statically typed*).  See [type system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a word: [Yes.](http://wingolog.org/archives/2011/08/02/a-closer-look-at-crankshaft-v8s-optimizing-compiler)

V8 compiles the code into an intermediary bytecode, then the "hotspots" are analyzed by the "Crankshaft" compiler, and if it determines that certain variables will never be anything other than an integer, a double, a string, or so on, it generates machine code with it "unboxed."

It only performs this optimization on branches that have already been traversed; others are deferred until information about the actual types involved are calculated by the "regular" engine, and then injected into the optimized code.

On top of this, V8 can translate essentially-static prototype hierarchies into "classic" C++-style object inheritance for performance improvements on "complex" types.

It can only do all of this, however, on code that is called "often"; like loops or frequently called functions.

The linked to article (part of a series), explains this in much, *much* more detail, and is definitely worth reading.

EDIT: But, of course, a statically-typed language like Java will optimize as much of the code as possible at compile time, so it *should* outperform Javascript in all but toy benchmarks. However, V8 is closing the gap between the two, and Javascript is a lot more "fun" to write than Java or C++, so initial prototyping or development of programs where the user is the largest source of latency means Javascript is often the better choice, in my opinion.

Comment: while your description is correct in spirit it contains a lot of misleading or wrong information about V8. for example: V8 compiles into machine code with one non-optimizing compiler (not into bytecode), then while program runs V8 tries to see hot functions which are discovered and optimize on function granularity (that is loop or an if branch can't be optimized separately, function is always optimized as whole [V8 might or might not insert unconditional deoptimization into code paths there were not executed but that is an implementation trick]).

Comment: I would say that there are three essential things here: 1) V8 is able to perform type/range/representation inference inside of function it optimizes 2) V8 is able to make optimistic assumptions about types/ranges/representations of variables and insert checks that would cause *deoptimization* when assumptions do not hold. 3) Global value numbering can eliminate and hoist checks to minimize impact.

Comment: @VyacheslavEgorov: Are you sure about that? [The page I linked to states that there is an intermediate code called 'Lithium' used by V8](http://wingolog.org/archives/2011/08/02/a-closer-look-at-crankshaft-v8s-optimizing-compiler)

Comment: yes, I am sure. Optimizing compiler (aka Crankshaft) uses two intermediate representations: high level one (called hydrogen) and low level one (called lithium), none of those are actually bytecode like and none of those are being executed and profiled directly. They are only used for optimization (hydrogen) and code generation (lithium). The code that runs before Crankshaft kicks in and optimizes function or after function was deoptimized is produced by a separate non-optimizing one pass compiler (aka full compiler) which does not use any IR and produces code directly from AST.